# Do we have an equivalent of rad2deg() in C++?

Tags: c++, degrees, radians

Do we have an equivalent of `rad2deg()` in `C++` ?

`rad2deg()` is available in `php, perl, Matlab, numpy-python`, etc.

It converts radians to degrees. This is the relationship:

```
π radian = 180°
```

Comment: No there's no such standard function in C++. But as you know it's a quite simple mathematical equation, that is easy to write a function for yourself.

Comment: No, but at least we now have `std::numbers::pi`. :/

Comment: Thanks @Someprogrammerdude.. I was just curious if there exist some function. Yes, formula is pretty simple.

Comment: even pi was added only rather recently to c++ https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/constants

Comment: Please do NOT make a `#define` called `PI` for pre-C++20 compilers (regardless of the precision).